# Query to Update Number of occurrences based on Case Persons in a Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, algorithm, t-sql

| CaseNumber | PersonNumber | PersonType | ID | GroupID | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13452400 | 134524 | Plaintiff | 1 | 10243 | NC |
| 13452400 | 2180207 | Defendant | 2 | 10243 | NC |
| 13452400 | 1320554 | Child | 3 | 10243 | NC |
| 13452402 | 134524 | Plaintiff | 4 | 10243 | AR |
| 13452402 | 38876453 | Defendant | 5 | 10243 | AR |
| 13452402 | 127673637 | Child | 6 | 10243 | AR |
| 14534301 | 38876453 | Plaintiff | 7 | 10243 | ID |
| 14534301 | 34276778 | Defendant | 8 | 10243 | ID |
| 14534301 | 98764356 | Child | 9 | 10243 | ID |
| 14534301 | 9808767 | Child | 10 | 10243 | ID |

I have huge data like that. Each case would have at least 3 people. One Person from one case may exists in multiple cases. child can be multiple. I can start loop for any person. If One PersonNumber from one case exists in any another case  on any role then

1.I need to update the IterationID of Parent person to 1 and IterationParent to same PersonNumber based on whom another case found.
2. Update first occurred record IterationID to 2. and Iteration Parent to PersonNumber of found person.

Here I need to pick the PersonNumbers where IterationID 2 and continue the search in another case If another case found I need to update the IterationID to 2 and IterationParent to the PersonNumber of found person ID.

Please find attached expected result here.

[image]

Comment: Do not post screenshots of your data!

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of data, as we cannot use it in our code. Please copy/paste all data into the question as text. Additionally, you have to show us what you have tried.

Comment: CaseNumber |  PersonNumber | PersonType | ID | GroupID | State
13452400    134524         Plaintiff         1 10243 NC
13452400    2180207         Defendant 2 10243 NC
13452400    1320554         Child         3 10243 NC
13452402    134524         Plaintiff         4 10243 AR
13452402    38876453     Defendant 5 10243 AR
13452402    127673637         Child         6 10243 AR
14534301    38876453         Plaintiff     7 10243 ID
14534301    34276778.     Defendant 8 10243 ID
14534301    98764356         Child         9 10243 ID
14534301     9808767         Child        10 10243 ID

Comment: Thanks for response. Posted Source Data in above comment. Please help me here.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70457366/edit) the additional information into your question . It is hard to read it as comment. Don't forget your  existing query

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm you are trying to implement using the sample data that you provided, e.g. instead of "one person" explain how the rows for `PersonNumber` `134524` are supposed to be processed. Are all of the columns in the sample data `NVarChar(MAX)`? Is the data type of all of the result columns `pixel`? How is that conversion done?

Comment: CaseNumber,PersonNumber,ID,GroupID are Integer. rest all are varchar(20)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DENSE_RANK` function to create an `IterationID` column and retrieve rows that have equal `IterationID` by selecting the first `PersonNumber` value using a select clause

```
WITH cte AS(
     SELECT *,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CaseNumber) AS IterationID
     FROM tb
)
SELECT t1.CaseNumber,
       t1.PersonNumber,
       t1.PersonType,
       t1.ID,
       t1.GroupID,
       t1.State,
       t1.IterationID,
       (SELECT TOP 1 t2.PersonNumber FROM cte t2 WHERE t1.IterationID = t2.IterationID) AS IterationPare
FROM cte t1
```

Demo in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5d684/1)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This query is giving random Iteration number with out checking personID matching. Only if Person ID matched then we need to update the column with IteartionID.                                                     
 1. If One PersonNumber matched in any case then we can populate the ItearationID.                                                                                              
2. IterationParent as matched person record.